# Calling webservice from UIAutomation

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Is it possible to call a webservice from `UIAutomation`?

on this webpage http://www.geonames.org/export/ajax-postalcode-autocomplete.html
it is possible to type in country and postal code, and get following reponse

http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=2830&country=DK&username=demo

```
 {"postalcodes":[{"postalcode":"2830","countryCode":"DK","lng":12.4666667,"placeName":"Virum","lat":55.8}]}
```

Im fairly new to this, is there a way i can call the service with arguments or build the url myself and call that and get a response as `JSON` into `UIAutomation`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = target.host().performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/curl", ["http://yoururl"], 30);
var json = JSON.parse(result.stdout)
```